# Does the noun "der Paprika" have a plural form? If so, how can I use it?

Tags: noun

I would like to say something like this:
**Ich hätte gerne zwei Paprika.**

Is it correct? Should I change it to "zwei Paprikas"?

My dictionaries show that Paprika doesn't have a plural form.

Pons: [no Plural for Paprika](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/Paprika?bidir=1)

[image]

Comment: The head of the block shows: `Pap·ri·ka <-s, -[s] [o. -, -[s]]> [ˈpaprika] SUBST m o f`. I don't know where this is explained, but it seems, that (one of) the `-[s]` is meant to denote the plural.

Comment: @user unknown It shows "-s" in plural, but it also says "kein Pl" - it's confusing

Comment: The dictionary says that there is no plural för meanings 1 and 2, but there is also 3.

Comment: @CarstenS: Technically, the OP explicitly mentions "der Paprika", whereas meaning 3 is noted to be exclusively used feminine in the quoted dictionary. I am not sure this exclusion was intentional, though. (With that said, there are regional variations and while I (S-W Germany) have never encountered "Paprika" with a masculine article, some of the linked samples contradict the claim that it there is an exclusive feminine usage for the "Schote".)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, I hadn't noticed that, thanks.

Comment: Duden knows two Paprikas. The plant https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Paprika_Pflanze_Gewuerz and the fruit https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Paprika_Paprikaschote_Gemuese. The latter can be DER or DIE while the first is DER. What are you looking for?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler I had in mind the vegetable (technically a fruit) der Paprika, the one you eat in salads, etc. I wanted to buy two or three bell peppers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Paprika_Pflanze_Gewuerz):

> Plural: die Paprika[s]

Du kannst sowohl sagen "Ich kaufe 2 Paprika" als auch "Ich kaufe 2 Paprikas."

Paprika wird im Dt. sowohl für die Frucht, als auch für das Gewürz verwendet, und wenn der Plural im Zshg. mit dem Gewürz eher selten gebraucht wird, so wird ein Gewürzhändler dennoch Gebrauch davon machen können, wenn er beispielsweise auf Hersteller/Marken oder Sorten bezugnehmend feststellt: "Ich habe 2 Salze (Meersalz und Bergwerkssalz), 5 Pfeffer (weiß, schwarz, grün, rot und bunt) und 2 Paprika[s] (mild und scharf)".

Comment: I understand if you prefer to answer in German even though the question is in English. But if you must do that, please do not use abbreviations like *Dt.* and *Zshg.* Some of us are not native speakers and abbreviations like this are sometimes difficult to understand.